# how to seed HTML Content to SQL?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to seed HTML contact to my table in SQL.

The field is of type nvarchar (50).

I'm writing in C# in .NET core.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did at the end was :
At my seeder file I added a function like this:

```
private void SeedTemplateEmailMessages()
        {
            var fileData = File.ReadAllText(GetFullFilePath("EmailHtmlTeplate.html"));

            _modelBuilder.Entity<EmailTemplateEntity>().HasData(new
            {
                ID = 0,
                Template = fileData,
            });
        }
```

my class looks like this :

```
 [Table("EmailTemplateTbl")]
    public partial class EmailTemplateEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
         
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        [MaxLength]
        public string Template { get; set; }
    }
```